# Regex string not start with sub-string for Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: regex, kubernetes

I want to use regex for path of Ingress in Kubernetes to match strings starting with `/app` but not starting with `/app/api`.

My application in fact is in `/app` prefix and the back end part has prefix `/app/api` and now I want to match all requests related to my application but do not belong to back end (which should go to front end part).
For this, I know that the PCRE regex is `/app(/|$)(?!api)(.*)`. **But** in the [documentations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/#regular-expression-support) of Ingress Kubernetes, it is mentioned that it supports [RE2 Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) which seems that doesn't support negative look-ahead (and many other features). How else I can specify this regex? or what other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

Just define both ingress objects - the one for the backend and the one for the frontend (you can even use prefix notation here). The [path priority rules](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/#path-priority) will order these entries accordingly.

Something like this should work:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app/api
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /app
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-service
          servicePort: 80
```